# React HOC with async call render component before the logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I would like to render a component only when I have a token and this one is valid. To check if the token is valid, I have to send a POST request to the API. I did that inside `componentWillMount`. I also tried to put that in componentDidMount, but always it renders first the Redirect and then the component which causes this error in console: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method in Authenticate (created by Route).` I simply would like to render the component if `authenticated: true`, else Redirect to the login route.

**authCheck.js**

```
export default (ComposedComponent) =>
    class Authenticate extends Component {

        state = {
            authenticated: false,
        };

        componentWillMount() {
            this.checkAndRedirect();
        }

        checkAndRedirect() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
            const config = {
                headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
            };
            if (token) {
                axios.post(
                    'https://alessandroarcidiaco.it/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate',
                    null,
                    config
                )
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res.status === 200) {
                            this.setState({authenticated: true})
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        this.setState({authenticated: false})
                    })
            } else {
                this.setState({authenticated: false});
            }
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.authenticated){
                return <ComposedComponent />
            }
            return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perform your async request inside an LSHook, or rewrite in the way that your function returns a promise that will be handled inside a hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seams that when the render() method runs the first time, your "this.state.authenticated" is "false" so you are redirected to "/login".

When the post request returns and the "this.state.authenticated" is set to "true" you will be already the "/login" screen.

You could fix it initializing the "authenticated" to "undefined"

```
state = {
    authenticated: undefined,
};
```

And only redirect if it was "false"

```
render() {
    if (this.state.authenticated){
        return <ComposedComponent />
    } else if ( this.state.authenticated === false) { //pay attention on '===', it is not '=='
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
    } else {
        <p>Loading...</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: `else {return null}` or some loading indicator

Answer (score 3):

You're using `componentWillMount`, which is an **unsafe** & **deprecated** method, and where you **should avoid side-effects**. (from [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount))

As the error said, you're updating state of a unmounted component : `checkAndRedirect` triggers `setState`s before the component is mounted, because it has been called in `componentWillMount`.

You have to use `componentDidMount` for doing such things and re-think your code, because as you said, you'll always fall into `<Redirect to="/login" />`. Initializing `authenticated` at `undefined` and playing on `true/false` in your render can do the job.

Comment: Yep! I also converted willMount with didMount. Thanks @samb102